# Monterey mail search not working

Tags: mail.app, spotlight, monterey, apple-silicon

I upgraded from an old (~10 years) Mac running Mojave to a new M1 mac running Monterey.  The upgrade was ok, but Mail does not return all possible results when I search it (I know this to be a fact because I need to search online with GMail on the browser to actually find anything).  No idea why.  Any suggestions on how to fix?

Apple silicon, MacOS 12.4, Mail 16.0

```
sudo mdutil -sa
/:
    Indexing enabled.
/System/Volumes/Data:
    Indexing enabled.
```

So it is not that (in case you were wondering).

Comment: You might want to trigger a reindex with mdutil; or it could still be indexing, if it's really new.

Comment: it is now two months old.  I am reindexing now, I'll report back

Comment: Reindexing did not work.  For my gmail account I still need to use Gmail on a browser to actually search my mail.  For the Exchange accounts, no such luck.